# GraphiQL query returning CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I'm just doing the tutorial @ https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/ to understand graphQL and graphene with Django 2.

I haven't used Django in a while, and the tut seems to be for Django 11. I'm getting a CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW when I try a GraphQL query like so:

```
query {
  allIngredients {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

The underlying json fixture looks like this:

```
[{"model": "ingredients.category", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Dairy"}}, {"model": "ingredients.category", "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "Meat"}}, {"model": "ingredients.ingredient", "pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Eggs", "notes": "Good old eggs", "category": 1}}, {"model": "ingredients.ingredient", "pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "Milk", "notes": "Comes from a cow", "category": 1}}, {"model": "ingredients.ingredient", "pk": 3, "fields": {"name": "Beef", "notes": "Much like milk, this comes from a cow", "category": 2}}, {"model": "ingredients.ingredient", "pk": 4, "fields": {"name": "Chicken", "notes": "Definitely doesn't come from a cow", "category": 2}}]
```

Forgive a noob, but there must be something that changed with Django 2? Is there another setting I need to apply?

In settings.py I have:

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'cookbook.schema.schema'
}
```

My folder structure is slightly different to the tut in that I have my ingredients app not nested within my cookbook app. The cookbook app is the main app like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: add `csrf_exempt` to your urls.py [0]

Long answer:

CSRF protection is nothing new in Django [1], you usually add `{{csrf_token}}` to your template, and then either use that (or the `csrftoken` cookie) as the `X-CSRFToken` header in your POST requests to the server.
However, if you are testing with Postman or similar, there is no valid CSRF token to use, so your best bet is to stop your views from expecting a CSRF token, which is what the `csrf_exempt` function above does.

[0] https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/61#issuecomment-261199128

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/